# Using COALESCE with numeric values

Tags: sql-server, null

I have the following code:

```
set @mystring = coalesce(numericval,'');
```

What I want is the following behaviour:

- numericval is null - set @mystring to blank
- numericval is not null then convert this to a string and set @mystring

I can't coelesce this to a numeric value, because that value will be output, and I can't convert it while it's null.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2012 `set @mystring = concat(numericval,'');`

Comment: Didn't realise that - but unfortunately it's 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  Declare @mystring as varchar(Max)
    set @mystring = coalesce(Cast(numericval as varchar),'');
    Select @mystring
```